# What does static imply in import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

Tags: java, mockito

What does `static` mean in

`import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;`

I have seen statements like `import java.util.*;` but it never had static.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[static](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) is a Java keyword (not specific to Mokito).  Statically importing a class allows you to use class members from the imported class without qualification.

So instead of doing something like this:

```
if (foo == Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS) {
```

You can do:

```
if (foo == CALLS_REAL_METHODS) {
```

Answer (score 0):

According the the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html),

1. The normal `import` declaration imports classes from packages, allowing them to be used without package qualification,
2. The `static` `import` declaration imports static members from classes, allowing them to be used without class qualification.

You can use it when you require frequent access to static members from one or two classes.

Comment: The question is a dupe. Dont be a rep monger.